# Gitosis installation error (AssertionError)

Tags: ubuntu, git

I am trying to set up a Git server in Ubuntu, but I can't get past this issue. I'm trying to add my public key to Gitosis thusly (as every tutorial so far has instructed me to do):

```
sudo -H -u git gitosis-init < /tmp/pcalves.pub
```

But keep getting hit with the same error messages:

```
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /var/git/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /var/git/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/     
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/bin/gitosis-init", line 9, in <module>
        load_entry_point('gitosis==0.2', 'console_scripts', 'gitosis-init')()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.6.egg/gitosis/app.py", line 24, in run
        return app.main()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.6.egg/gitosis/app.py", line 38, in main
        self.handle_args(parser, cfg, options, args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.6.egg/gitosis/init.py", line 140, in handle_args
        run_hook.post_update(cfg=cfg, git_dir=admin_repository)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.6.egg/gitosis/run_hook.py", line 43, in post_update
        config=cfg,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.6.egg/gitosis/gitdaemon.py", line 79, in set_export_ok
        assert ext == '.git'
    AssertionError
```

Even though the first two lines show the expected result, it doesn't seem to be working, as afterwards, if I try to clone the repository in my local machine, I get this:

```
fatal: 'gitosis-admin.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: Fixed the issue by using Gitolite instead.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, so just answering for the archives.

Check the names of directories in `/var/git/repositories/`; make sure that all the git repositories end with `.git`.